# How do I select all from one table while selecting an average from another table PHP/SQL?

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I have a table named dining_listings. This table has an auto-increment primary-key that serves as its identification reference. Meanwhile, I have another table called dining_reviews that contains the reviews and ratings for the dining_listings table. The id of the dining_listings table corresponds with the place_id of the dining_reviews table.

If I have an id of 7 for the dining_listings table, there can be multiple 7's for the place_id column in the dining_reviews table.

```
 +----------+-----------+--------------
 id           name        city
 +----------+-------------+--------------
 1            wok house    cityville
 +----------+-------------+--------------
 2            tastyXpress  townsville
 +----------+-------------+--------------
```

The dining_reviews table:

```
 +-----------+-----------+----------------
 id           place_id     overall_rating
 +-----------+-----------+----------------
 1            2            5
 +-----------+-----------+----------------
 2            2            4
```

I figured I would use a "Left Join" for these two tables. But I want to select all from one table while selecting the average of a column from another.

Then the next challenge comes echoing it out in PHP

Comment: I wanted to add...I have a solution, but it involves placing a query within a query in PHP, which I do not want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT d.id, d.name, d.city, AVG(l.column) FROM dining_listings d LEFT JOIN dining_reviews l on d.id=l.place_id");

// $con is the connection variable ... $con = mysqli_connect(...
```

**You said:**

When I tried something like that with

```
 while($row = $stmt->fetch_object())
{
      echo $row->id;  
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->rating
}
```

I recieved a "fetch_object() on boolean" error message from PHP

**Here is a working example:**

```
// If you still get a boolean after trying this then the problem is in the query
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "databaseName");

$query = "SELECT d.id, d.name, d.city, AVG(l.column) FROM dining_listings d LEFT JOIN dining_reviews l on d.id=l.place_id";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    // fetch object array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        echo $row->id;   // You should now be able to see the output
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->rating
    }

// free result set
$result->close();
}

// close connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: I tried something just like that, but received a "fetch_object() on boolean" error. I am trying to loop through the listings table and echo everything out in addition to the average rating that corresponds with that listing

Comment: @Johnny2x4 tell me if that solves your problem, I just edited.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan86. I figured it out. The only thing extra that need to be added is GROUP BY for it to work. And I used AVG(1.column) AS rating.

Comment: @Johnny2x4 No problem, glad to hear you got it working. Peace

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join to select all from `dining_listings` table and also average `overall_rating` from the other table `dining_reviews` as given below:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.CITY, AVG(B.OVERALL_RATING)
FROM
DINING_LISTINGS A
LEFT JOIN
DINING_REVIEWS B
ON A.ID = B.PLACE_ID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME, A.CITY
ORDER BY AVG(B.OVERALL_RATING) DESC;
```

Comment: I recieved an error message "fetch_object() on boolean" when attempting to try something like this.